# How can I organize this data using Perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I have an input file such as:

```
a 7 5
b 8 2    
a 3 2   
b 4 1    
c 6 1
```

How can I get output like

`column_1_val`, `number_occurrence_column_1`, `sum_of_column_2`, `sum_of_column_3`

For example

```
a 2 10 7
b 2 12 3
c 1 6 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The program below is a possible solution. I have used the `DATA` file handle whereas you will presumably need to open an external file and use the handle from that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($key, @vals) = split;
  $data{$key}[0]++;
  my $i;
  $data{$key}[++$i] += $_ for @vals;
}

say join ' ', $_, @{$data{$_}} for sort keys %data;

__DATA__
a 7 5
b 8 2    
a 3 2   
b 4 1    
c 6 1
```

**output**

```
a 2 10 7
b 2 12 3
c 1 6 1
```

Comment: try `join " "` and you can have unlimited number of column.

Comment: Thank you. Since the rest of my program supports an indefinite number of values I have adopted your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like (untested):

```
while (<>) {
    if (m/(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
        ($n, $r1, $r2) = ($1, $2, $3);

        $nr{$n}++;
        $r1{$n} += $r1;
        $r2{$n} += $r2;
    }
}

for $n (sort keys %nr) {

    print "$n $nr{$n} $r1{$n} $r2{$n}\n";
}
```

This is a very quick-and-dirty way of doing what you described, but it should get you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Even i am not aware of perl.But in case you are concerned with the result.the below is the solution in awk.It might /might not help you.but in case u need it :

```
awk '{c[$1]++;a[$1]=a[$1]+$2;b[$1]+=$3}END{for(i in a)print i,c[i],a[i],b[i]}' file3
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take:

my %records;

```
while ( <> ) {
    my @cols = split ' ';
    my $rec  = $records{ $cols[0] } ||= {};
    $rec->{number_occurrence_column_1}++;
    $rec->{sum_of_column_2} += $cols[1];
    $rec->{sum_of_column_3} += $cols[2];
}

foreach my $rec ( map { { col1 => $_, %{ $records{ $_ } } } 
          sort keys %records 
        ) { 
    print join( "\t"
              , @$rec{ qw<col1 number_occurrence_column_1 
                          sum_of_column_2 sum_of_column_3
                         > 
                     } 
              ), "\n"
       ;
}
```